# Is there a way to automatically maximize a window when dragging it to an external monitor?

Tags: macos, display, window-manager, mission-control

I can do it with a shortcut, but looking for a fully automated way.

Does Mission Control or macOS allow this?

Answer (score 1):

I use the app [BetterSnapTool](https://folivora.ai/bettersnaptool), which allows you to maximize windows by dragging them to the middle of the top of the screen, among other features.